# Evaluate a string read from a file in perl

Tags: string, perl, eval, evaluate

Made up example (perl):

```
my $x = read_input_from_file();

# $x now contains string $ENV{SOMETHING}/dir/$ENV{SOMETHING_ELSE}
my $y = eval($x);  # doesnt work
```

How can I get value of string contained in $x in the script?

So far I have tried using `eval` which doesn't generate any output. I am hoping that something already exists in perl and these string expressions do not need to be parsed and evaluated.

Comment: (1) it should work (2) it is a serious security concern to `eval` data coming from outside your code.

Comment: It doesn't work because division by zero; try inspecting the value of `$@`. You could try adding quotes around the variable, e.g. `eval("\"$x\"")`.

Comment: My thanks to you both.

Comment: `$ENV{SOMETHING}/dir/$ENV{SOMETHING_ELSE}` is not valid Perl code. (Well, it is, but it's a pair of divisions.)

Comment: If this is some way to read settings from a file, there are probably better ways of doing it. If you include a description of what you are trying to do, someone might be able to advice you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "string" [eval](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval) is a little specific:

> `eval` in all its forms is used to execute a little Perl program.
> ...
> In a string eval, the value of the expression (which is itself determined within scalar context) is first parsed, and if there were no errors, executed as a block within the lexical context of the current Perl program.

So this evaluates *code*, and with a variable to be evaluated containing a string literal we have a "bareword" ("*Unquoted string*") which is generally no good.  In your case, those `/` in `$x` cause additional trouble.

If the content of the variable to evaluate is a string literal (not code) it need be quoted

```
my $y = eval q(") . $x . q(");  # double-quote so that it interpolates
```

I use the [operator form of a single quote](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#q/STRING/), `q()`. Quoted under it is a double-quote since `$x` itself seems to contain variables that need be evaluated (interpolated).  Another way is to form and quote the string directly, by using the operator form for double-quotes, `qq("$x")`.

Keep in mind that running code from external sources can be a serious security problem.